# What percentage of Twitch tipping now occurs with Bitcoin?

Tags: paypal, gaming

How does Bitcoin tipping compare to PayPal? Are there projections for when cryptocurrency tipping will surpass PayPal for revenue on the platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is something only Twitch could publish.

They don't even mention Bitcoin in their [2015 Retrospective](https://www.twitch.tv/year/2015), but maybe they will for the 2016 one.